# Do I make an after-bracha after drinking water?

Tags: blessing, water

I heard once that I only make a bracha before drinking the water, is this true?
Thanks!

Comment: No. You need to make an after brocha as well.

Comment: https://www.brachos.org/brachos/water/

Comment: Water is often drunk for non-hana'ah reasons, such as swallowing a pill, where you don't make any bracha. Perhaps you are getting confused with this or something similar

Comment: The Gemara Eruvin 14B and Nidda 51B seems to indicate that No bracha is required after drinking water. However The Halacha doesn’t follow this view.

Comment: Great, thanks All. If anyone has sources and posts an answer, I'll upvote their answer below.